# Error in compiling app with MoPub-Fabric iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator, twitter-fabric, mopub

I am using MoPub kit using Fabric SDKs.
Everything works fine on all devices until you run the app on iPad simulator.
Running the app on iPad simulator gives following error while compiling the app:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0D81.png)

[image]

P.S. I am using XCode 7.3

Edit 1: I get following warnings also while running the app on simulators.

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Projects/Directory/Directory_iOS/PassKit.framework/PassKit.tbd, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/Projects/Directory/Directory_iOS/PassKit.framework/PassKit.tbd

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Projects/Directory/Directory_iOS/MoPub.framework/MoPub, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/Projects/Directory/Directory_iOS/MoPub.framework/MoPub (4 slices)

Only running the app on the iPad causes compilation errors iPhone simulators is not a problem with it.